# scrolling a UIScrollView Programmatically

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiscrollview

I want an idea to scroll a UIScrollView without user inputs. how to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[scrollView setContentOffset: whereINeedToScrollTo animated: YES];`